# Fitting linear model / ANOVA by group

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, anova

I'm trying to run `anova()` in R and running into some difficulty. This is what I've done up to now to help shed some light on my question.

Here is the `str()` of my data to this point.

```
 str(mhw)
'data.frame':   500 obs. of  5 variables:
$ r    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ c    : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
$ grain: num  3.63 4.07 4.51 3.9 3.63 3.16 3.18 3.42 3.97 3.4 ...
$ straw: num  6.37 6.24 7.05 6.91 5.93 5.59 5.32 5.52 6.03 5.66 ...
$ Quad : Factor w/ 4 levels "NE","NW","SE",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

Column r is a numerical value indicating which row in the field an individual plot resides
Column c is a numerical value indicating which column an individual plot resides
Column Quad corresponds to the geographical location in the field to which each plot resides

```
Quad <- ifelse(mhw$c > 13 & mhw$r < 11, "NE",ifelse(mhw$c < 13 & mhw$r < 11,"NW", ifelse(mhw$c < 13 & mhw$r >= 11, "SW","SE")))
mhw <- cbind(mhw, Quad)
```

I have fit a `lm()` as follows

```
nov.model <-lm(mhw$grain ~ mhw$straw)
anova(nov.model)
```

This is an `anova()` for the entire field, which is testing grain yield against straw yield for each plot in the dataset.

My trouble is that I want to run an individual `anova()` for the Quad column of my data to test grain yield and straw yield in each quadrant.

perhaps a `with()` might fix that. I have never used it before and I am in the process of learning R currently. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `by` facility in R.

```
fit <- with(mhw, by(mhw, Quad, function (dat) lm(grain ~ straw, data = dat)))
```

Since you have 4 levels in `Quad`, you end up with 4 linear models in `fit`, i.e., `fit` is a "by" class object (a type of "list") of length 4.

To get coefficient for each model, you can use

```
sapply(fit, coef)
```

To produce model summary, use

```
lapply(fit, summary)
```

To export ANOVA table, use

```
lapply(fit, anova)
```

---

As a reproducible example, I am taking the example from `?by`:

```
tmp <- with(warpbreaks,
            by(warpbreaks, tension,
               function(x) lm(breaks ~ wool, data = x)))

class(tmp)
# [1] "by"

mode(tmp)
# [1] "list"

sapply(tmp, coef)

#                    L         M         H
#(Intercept)  44.55556 24.000000 24.555556
#woolB       -16.33333  4.777778 -5.777778

lapply(tmp, anova)

#$L
#Analysis of Variance Table
#
#Response: breaks
#          Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value  Pr(>F)  
#wool       1 1200.5 1200.50  5.6531 0.03023 *
#Residuals 16 3397.8  212.36                  
#---
#Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
#
#$M
#Analysis of Variance Table
#
#Response: breaks
#          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#wool       1  102.72 102.722  1.2531 0.2795
#Residuals 16 1311.56  81.972               
#
#$H
#Analysis of Variance Table
#
#Response: breaks
#          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
#wool       1  150.22 150.222  2.3205 0.1472
#Residuals 16 1035.78  64.736
```

---

I was aware of this option, but not familiar with it. Thanks to [@Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1412059/roland) for providing code for the above reproducible example:

```
library(nlme)
lapply(lmList(breaks ~ wool | tension, data = warpbreaks), anova)
```

For your data I think it would be

```
fit <- lmList(grain ~ straw | Quad, data = mhw)
lapply(fit, anova)
```

You don't need to install `nlme`; it comes with R as one of recommended packages.

Comment: Thank you. This provides the `coef` of the data. If I wanted to produce the full anova summary to test the hypothesis, "Does grain yield differ in East Quadrants to West Quadrants". How can I produce that with `fit`

Comment: Worked Perfect. Thank you very much for the help. I apologize for the simple nature of the questions. As I said I'm in the process of learning R and get a little turned around on ,my syntax.

Comment: That link is quite helpful. That cleared up many of my side questions that came up as I was working with R.

Comment: Or use `lmList`: `library(nlme); lapply(lmList(breaks ~ wool | tension, data = warpbreaks), anova)`